# Passing Integer variable into a Pandas function

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a Pandas dataframe of 5 columns (types listed below) and code that applies two user functions. I am trying to pass an integer variable into the function:

Calculates the date x months prior to the Reporting Date
(integer variable)

```
def calc_end_window_date_2(row, pr_Months):
    s = row['REPORTING_DATE']

    return (s + relativedelta(months=-pr_Months)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

```
df.loc[:, 'WindowEnd'] = df.apply(calc_end_window_date_2, pr_Months=-6)
```

TypeError: ("calc_end_window_date_2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pr_Months'", 'occurred at index REPORTING_DATE')

I then removed "row" from the function and 
TypeError: ("calc_end_window_date_2() got multiple values for argument 'pr_Months'", 'occurred at index REPORTING_DATE')

How do i pass a variable into a generic function?

Comment: I think you may just need to add `axis=1` to your `.apply()` if you want it to operate at a row level

Comment: you function is a bit weird with 2 returns, but I think because you apply on a dataframe, you need to specify axis=1 in the apply like `df.apply(calc_end_window_date_2, pr_Months=-6, axis=1)`

Comment: I edited the code wrt the multiple returns (not watching my attempts to debug)

Comment: 'df.loc[:, 'WindowEnd'] = df.apply(calc_end_window_date_2, pr_Months=-6, axis=1)'
Does the trick.

Comment: @BMoore if your function does only add 6 months from a date, then you should not use apply but try DateOffset like just `(df['REPORTING_DATE'] + pd.DateOffset(months=6)).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: That's a much better answer. I should have seen that before. Thanks for your help.